# Python inheritance AttributeError: type object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, python-requests

I have a class `RequestsSession` inheriting from resquests.Session (documentation for reference https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) has an attribute `proxies`. But when I try to call it, I get an error
`AttributeError: type object 'RequestsSession' has no attribute 'proxies'`

This is how `RequestsSession` class is:

```
#test.py
 
import requests
 
def requests_session(proxies):
  
   class RequestsSession(requests.Session):
 
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.trust_env = False
           self.proxies = proxies
 
   return RequestsSession
```

And this is how it is called:

```
#proxy.py
 
from test import requests_session
 
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy:8080', 'https': 'http://proxy:8080'}
 
extra_headers = requests_session(proxies)
 
print(vars(extra_headers.__init__))
print(extra_headers.proxies)
```

And this is the error log:

```
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxy.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(extra_headers.__init__.proxies)
AttributeError: type object 'RequestsSession' has no attribute 'proxies'
```

Comment: Why do you have a class definition inside a function? I don't see anywhere where you're instantiating a `RequestsSession` object either.

Comment: Right, I missed this instantiation of the `RequestsSession` .  I was scratching my head for a day or 2. Class definition inside a function because of a different purpose as this is a piece of code from another project where I need that functionality.